# How to check last digit of number

Tags: python

Is there a way to get the last digit of a number. I am trying to find variables that end with "1" like 1,11,21,31,41,etc..

If I use a text variable I can simply put

```
print number[:-1]
```

but it works for variables with text(like "hello) but not with numbers.  With numbers I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I am trying to see if there's a better way to deal with numbers this way.  I know a solution is to convert to a string and then do the above command but I'm trying to see if there's another way I have missed.

Thanks so much in advance...

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Remainder when dividing by 10, as in

```
numericVariable % 10
```

This only works for positive numbers. -12%10 yields 8

Answer (score 23):

Use the modulus operator with 10:

```
num = 11
if num % 10 == 1:
    print 'Whee!'
```

This gives the remainder when dividing by 10, which will always be the last digit (when the number is positive).

Comment: Note that this will not work as expected for negatives: (`-3 % 10 == 7`)

Comment: @cobbal: Good point. In this case, you could take the absolute value first: `abs(num) % 10`

Answer (score 21):

So you want to access the digits in a integer like elements in a list; easiest way I can think of is:

```
n = 56789
lastdigit = int(repr(n)[-1])
# >  9
```

Convert **n** into a string, accessing last element then use int constructor to convert back into integer.

For a Floating point number:

```
n = 179.123
fstr = repr(n)
signif_digits, fract_digits = fstr.split('.')
# >  ['179', '123']
signif_lastdigit = int(signif_digits[-1])
# >  9
```

Comment: I just realized it's much better to use repr(n) in place of str(n) as with some numbers typecasting to string may lose accuracy.
No idea why but I've just seen it happen when playing with floating point numbers.

Answer (score 3):

I can't add a comment yet, but I wanted to iterate and expand on what Jim Garrison said

Remainder when dividing by 10, as in
numericVariable % 10

This only works for positive numbers. -12%10 yields 8

While modulus (%) is working as intended, throw on an absolute value to use the modulus in this situation.

```
abs(numericVariable) % 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Lostsoul, this should work:

```
    number = int(10)
#The variable number can also be a float or double, and I think it should still work.
lastDigit = int(repr(number)[-1])
#This gives the last digit of the variable "number." 
if lastDigit == 1 : 
    print("The number ends in 1!")
```

Instead of the print statement at the end, you can add code to do what you need to with numbers ending in 1.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Convert to string first:

```
oldint = 10101
newint = int(str(oldint)[-1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most efficient way is to use the reminder :

```
last_digit = orginal_number % 10
```

Comment: this has already been provided by several other answers....

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple yet effective way to do it

```
if number < 0:
       remainder = number % -10
else:
       remainder = number % 10
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

By using iteration and the in built function of 'digit' the number is treated as binary and so it goes from backwards to forwards. Here is an example of a bit of code for you.

```
for digit in binary:
    denary= denary*2 + int(digit)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this **efficient one-liner code** to call the last digit of any integer.
The logic is first to convert the given value to a string and then convert it into the list to call the last digit by calling the -1 index. After that, convert it into an integer to wrap it up.

**val** is a variable that represents any integer.

```
int(list(str(val))[-1])
```

Example:

```
val = 23442
int(list(str(val))[-1])`
```

**Output:** 2

Comment: 1. This approach has already been provided, and 2. You don't need to convert a string to list just to be able to index into it.