# How to check if a python string list contains a specific character in the last letter of a string?

Tags: python, list

I want to know how to search on a list of strings if some of them contain a specific char in the last letter. I was trying this:

```
uwu=[676, 23, 11];
zwz=3;
L_final=[];
l_final= [zwz in range(i[-1]) for i in uwu]:
```

Comment: Related: [How to check last digit of number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254827/how-to-check-last-digit-of-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to cast the elements to `string` if you want to look at individual characters. Other than that, you need to put an `if` in your list comprehension to only select those elements of `uwu` that end with the string representation of `zwz`:

```
uwu=[676, 23, 11]
zwz=3
L_final=[i for i in uwu if str(i)[-1] == str(zwz)]

>>> L_final
[23]
```

Comment: `L_final = [i for i in uwu if i % 10 == zwz]`