# last digit of number

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to do like this
(get last digit of number in dict):

```
year = age.get(user_id)
if year[-1] == 1:
   pass
```

but got this error `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: The error tells you exactly what’s going you.  An integer cannot be sliced, only a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If year is an integer, you can use `year % 10` to get the last digit.

`%` is called the modulus operator and it tells you the remainder after dividing the left side by the right.

Comment: What if `year` is somehow negative?

Comment: Try it: `python` / 
`>>> -22 % 10`  / 
`8`

Comment: -22's last digit is not 8, is it?

Comment: If you need to process negative years, then use `abs(year) % 10`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the year parameter from `integer` into `string` (using `str(year)`) in order to be able to use `slicing`

Like this:

```py
year = age.get(user_id)
if str(year)[-1] == "1":
   pass
```

Although it would be better to use modulo (remainder after division by 10) which will get you the last digit, if the number is positive integer:

```py
year = age.get(user_id)
last_digit = year % 10
```

In case it is negative you could take absolute value of the year to still get the correct answer (`abs(year) % 10`)

*Note that this was already asked in: [How to check last digit of number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254827/how-to-check-last-digit-of-number)*

Comment: That will not work. `str(year)[-1]` will return a string representation of `1` and not the int representation.

Comment: @SwetankPoddar you are right, I'll edit the answer

Comment: Also, just a suggestion, if you see that the question is already answered... you should flag the question rather than including a link to it in your answer :) Good job btw. Welcome to SO :D

Answer (score 0):

Year must be an int.

Try:

```
if year % 10 == 1:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If `year` is a String you can get last digit as you given. But your `age.get(user_id)` returns a integer you cannot get last digit as you given. You have find a numerical way like:

```
if year%10 == 1:
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

when you're dealing with digits in a number, you can treat the number as a string, then it will work

```
year = age.get(user_id)
year = str(year)
if year[-1] == '1':
   pass
```